# Cannot add class to a managed package

Tags: managed-package

I am developing a package and have made it managed so I can deploy it to my company's Group Edition org so I can test it out.

I now need to add a new class to the package, but it isn't listed in the classes I cant add from the Add to Package interface.

Is there some kind of requirement to add a completely new class to a managed package? The class is a RestResource if that makes a difference

thanks.

Comment: Is the class already added? If you've referenced that class in another class that is already managed then it will automatically get added.

Comment: Ah, of course. Its referenced by the tests. Silly me. If you add this as a response I'll mark it as accepted, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've referenced that class in another class that is already managed then it will automatically get added.